# ElectronNet publish app to single-file error with referenced assembly

Tags: .net, electron, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to `electronize` my blazor app. The app references another project that compiles to a dll.

So according to [this thread](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/netsdk1099-publishing-to-single-file-is-only-supported-for-executable/) this is reason 1 and I should expect this error - which I can fix when I try to publish the app by specifying `MyApp` and it works fine :

```
dotnet electronize build MyMainApp /target win /PublishReadyToRun true
```

Now the issue is when I want to run the app via `electronize start` the following command is generated automatically

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c "Debug" --output "C:\MyApp\obj\Host\bin" /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true --no-self-contained
```

And I can't find a way to remove the `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` part so it does NOT apply to the referenced project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix documented in the [GibHub Issues](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/532)

```
electronize build /target win /PublishSingleFile false /PublishReadyToRun false
```